# I have created a simple WCF web services and when I hosted on a remote service I am getting the following error:

Tags: wcf

Error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference1.IService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Can someone help me please with regards to the endpoint configuration?

When the service was running on the local machine the client was pointing at the following:

```
<endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
    address="http://localhost:54651/Service1.svc"  
    binding="basicHttpBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" 
    contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" />
```

What do we need to write when the service is running on the web hosting service?

Comment: Post your client and service config files.

Comment: Are you hosting this WCF service inside of IIS, or are you self-hosting it?

Comment: Did it work when it was on the local machine?   Where is the service now?  Please post the **current** service and client config files - the error message itself is pretty explanatory, and without further information from you this is nothing but a guessing game.

Comment: Yes, it was  working on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're hosting it in IIS Express on your local/dev machine.

Are you also using IISExpress or IIS? Verify if the service on the remote machine can be accessed at http://localhost:54651/Service1.svc. Your port number might be different or the address may have to be changed completely when you installed it. Change the address in the configuration file to wherever the service actually is and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If it was working on your local machine - my guess is you made a classic edit error. The http://localhost:54651/Service1.svc"  service address in your config file needs to be changed according to your service location and your client will need to point to that as well. 
Just a guess..